# Windows Server - Task Scheduler - Show which action is running

Tags: powershell, scheduled-tasks

OS - Windows Server 2012

I have an inventory scheduled task that has 31 actions.  Each action runs a different Powershell script.  If one of the actions/Powershell scripts is stuck, I want to know which one it is so I know which one may have a coding issue.

Is there any way to indicate which action is running out of the 31?  Is there a Powershell script that I can run where I enter the scheduled task name and it will return something like "Processing 18 or 31 actions"?

Something to add to this script:

```
Get-ScheduledTask |where TaskName -EQ 'Inventory_Part3'| Get-ScheduledTaskInfo
```

Comment: Under the History Tab in Task Scheduler you can see which individual action has started and completed

Answer (score 0):

1. If the powershell.exe process is "hung" as in still running, you could find the action via the script name passed to the `PowerShell.exe` process by the task scheduling system.

   You'd need to use `Get-WMIObject -ClassName Win32_Process` to access the arguments passed to the process, as explained in answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17563411/how-to-get-command-line-info-for-a-process-in-powershell-or-c-sharp)
2. [Answers to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46452001/task-scheduler-get-history-information-into-script-variables) indicate where the operational history of the task scheduler is stored in the Windows Event log. Per-action log entries may be available and filterable by your own powershell script.
3. Lower level WMI/CIM objects may contain more information than that exposed by the `*-ScheduledTask` cmdlets. You could explore classes like  `MSFT_ScheduledTask` and `MSFT_TaskAction` with `Get-CimClass`.

   At first glance it doesn't seem like there is any kind of `CurrentAction` attribute, but further digging could unearth something usable.

The live status of your tasks should be visible through the `Schedule.Service` COM object. Unfortunately I'm limited to Linux right now, so I don't have access to a test environment.

In broad strokes:

1. Here is a [vbscript examples of querying the task scheduler service here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/TaskSchd/displaying-task-names-and-state--scripting-). The Task Scheduler is exposed as a COM object `Schedule.Service`, which PowerShell should be able to manipulate.
2. The [TaskService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/TaskSchd/taskservice) object has a [GetRunningTasks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/TaskSchd/taskservice-getrunningtasks) member that should return you a collection of...
3. [RunningTask](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/TaskSchd/runningtask) objects, which have the [CurrentAction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/TaskSchd/runningtask-currentaction) property

I suspect the code would look something like this (but again, I have nowhere to test):

```
$TaskScheduleService = New-Object -comobject 'Schedule.Service'
$TaskScheduleService.Connect()
$RunningTasks = $TaskScheduleService.GetRunningTasks()
$RunningTasks | Where-Object {<#some kind of filter to get only your tasks#>} |
    Foreach-Object {
        $_.CurrentAction
    }
```