# Get start end time of specific task in event log

Tags: powershell, get-winevent

Hey i am trying to get the start and finish time of a scheduled task in the event log.

I followed the steps here [Task Scheduler - get history information into script variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46452001/task-scheduler-get-history-information-into-script-variables)  But i can not figure out how to modify it to get just the info from one task.

I have tried to modify the hashtable filter

```
`$EventFilter = @{
    LogName = 'Microsoft-Windows-TaskScheduler/Operational'
    Id = 100
    TaskName = '\Repository'
    StartTime = [datetime]::Now.AddDays(-1)
}`
```

But that returns the error

> Get-WinEvent : No events were found that match the specified selection criteria.

I have tried to find info on this but i can't seem to find anything that points to getting just one task.

Any help would be welcome.

Comment: Do you have Task History enabled?

Comment: Yes i can see the task history in the gui. both in the task scheduler and the event log

Comment: Look at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46452001/task-scheduler-get-history-information-into-script-variables)

Comment: Yes that is was i used to try and build what i have, but putting in the taskname still does not return anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer [Here](https://4sysops.com/archives/fast-event-log-search-in-powershell-with-the-filterhashtable-parameter/)  It seems instead of searching for the data name xml you just search data with any of the fields that can be there.

Hope that makes sense.